# Creating a new access table and name it from textbox

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am Trying to create New access table in a database but when i tries to name it from text box it is giving error

Sub CreateTable()

```
Dim strCreate As String = "CREATE TABLE"& TxtBoxTb1Name.Text &(" & _
```

"CountryName varchar(120) Primary key," & _
        "Continent Integer," & _
        "Area Long," & _
        "Population Long," & _
        "Capital varchar(80)," & _
        "Code char(2));"

```
    Dim conDatabase As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""Data Source=" & filename & ".mdb;")
    Dim cmdDatabase As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strCreate, conDatabase)
    conDatabase.Open()
    cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conDatabase.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Table Created Sucessfully")
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Naming a access Table From textbox's text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433029/naming-a-access-table-from-textboxs-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the sintax to define the primary key, and be careful with the spaces and commas when you create SQL statements. Below is the fixed code that works.

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private filename As String = "SampleDB.mdb"

```
Private Sub CreateTable()
    Dim strCreate As String = "CREATE TABLE " &
        TxtBoxTb1Name.Text & "(_Continent Integer, " & "_Area Long, " & "_Population Long," & "_Capital varchar(80)," & "_Code Char(2)," & "_CountryName varchar(120) CONSTRAINT MyFieldConstraint PRIMARY KEY)"

    Dim conDatabase As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; " &
        "Data Source=" & Path.GetFullPath(filename) & "; User Id=admin;
        Password =;")
    conDatabase.Open()
    Dim cmdDatabase As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strCreate, conDatabase)

    cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conDatabase.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Table Created Sucessfully")

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CreateTable()
End Sub
```

End Class