# Naming a access Table From textbox's text

Tags: vb.net

I am Trying to create New access table in a database but when i try to name it from text box it is giving an error

Sub CreateTable()

```
 Dim strCreate As String = "CREATE TABLE" & TxtBoxTblName.Text &(" & _
    "CountryName varchar(120) Primary key," & _
    "Continent Integer," & _
    "Area Long," & _
    "Population Long," & _
    "Capital varchar(80)," & _
    "Code char(2));"


    Dim conDatabase As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""Data Source=" & filename & ".mdb;")
    Dim cmdDatabase As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strCreate, conDatabase)
    conDatabase.Open()
    cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conDatabase.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Table Created Sucessfully")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you missed a `"` in this line `"CREATE TABLE" & TxtBoxTblName.Text &(" & _` and these in no space after `CREATE TABLE` keyword that will also yields error. so it should be  `"CREATE TABLE " & TxtBoxTblName.Text &"(" & _` See the difference [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/qadkuqhu) **or** try below code

```
Dim STR_DDL As String
STR_DDL = "CREATE TABLE #TABLENAME# (CountryName varchar(120) Primary key,Continent Integer,Area Long,Population Long,Capital varchar(80),Code char(2));"
STR_DDL.Replace("#TABLENAME#", Trim(TxtBoxTblName.Text))
```

***OR***

using [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim STR_DDL As String = String.Format("CREATE TABLE {0} (CountryName varchar(120) Primary key " & _
                                ",Continent Integer,Area Long,Population Long,Capital varchar(80) " & _
                                ",Code char(2));", Trim(TxtBoxTblName.Text))
```

`{0}` is a place holder for `TxtBoxTblName.Text`

and use it

```
Dim cmdDatabase As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(STR_DDL , conDatabase)
```

Comment: Thanks it works but 1 more issue arises when i was creating new Database and table at one time,now database is creating but cannot able to create table in that database and iam thinking that new created Database is not closing so create table subroutine is not able to open the database to insert a new table.. sending u code .....

Comment: 'BROWSE BUTTON
    Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBrowse.Click
        Dim fbd = New FolderBrowserDialog()         'FOLDER DIALOG BROWSER CREATOR
        fbd.Description = "Select a folder for the new database"
        fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
        fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = True
        If fbd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'TRYING TO CREATE  NEW DATABASE AND TABLE
            Try
                Dim filepath = Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, TxtBoxTblName.Text & ".mdb")
                DbCreator()

Comment: Catch ex As Exception

                MessageBox.Show("Unable to create database")      
            End Try
            Try
                CreateTable()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("unable to create table")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: 'NEW DATABASE CREATOR 
    Sub DbCreator()
        Dim cat As Catalog = New Catalog()
        filename = TxtBoxDbName.Text



        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=F:\check\" & filename & ".mdb;" & _
                    "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")

        MessageBox.Show("Database Created Successfully")

        cat = Nothing
        
  

    End Sub